# QTP/VBScript Syntax of constructor call

Tags: syntax, vbscript, qtp

Not using QTP myself, but trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12302039/603855), I desperately need to know, whether this valid VBScript:

```
Class C
  Function init(x, y)
    Set init = Me
  End Function
 End Class

 Dim o : Set o = New C.init(0, 1)
```

will cause a syntax error in QTP - or more generally: Does QTP implement its own dialect of VBScript?

Comment: Tested it in QTP and it works (I was not aware I could use that construct). FYI: When you are advising people with QTP, keep in mind that classes are always private to the library file it is in. When you want to use a class in QTP throughout the whole set of libraries, you have to make a public function in the same library file where the class is in that returns an instance of that object. That is why most of the time the instantiation of an object is done outside the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid in QTP too.

QTP uses VBScript as the engine for running tests, there are some extensions on the language that allow using test objects but most of these just look like global functions and objects. As far as I know nothing is *removed* from VBScript.

The limitations QTP has regarding class types are regarding intellisense and such not execution of the test/script.